# How do I call a c function from C#

Tags: c#, c, callback

I would like to use this C function in C#:

```
typedef void (*WRITE_CALLBACK)(int hMountEnv, unsigned __int64 NumBytesWritten, 
               void* pContext);
```

How would I go about defining it so I can call it?

Do I need to do anything else to make this work?

Comment: in what context does this stand? do you want to use some unmanaged lib in c#? or do you want to get the "c# version" of that function pointer?

Comment: Yes, I want to use some unmanaged lib in C# and to get the C# version of that function pointer.

Comment: It is a function pointer declaration, not a function.  The equivalent of a delegate type in C#.  You can't call a type.

Comment: in that case you should have a look at the link provided by AnitKryst ... everything you need is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ektebyzx(v=vs.80).aspx for how to marshal function pointers. There is an example on the bottom of that page.

I'll do the C# for you, and since I don't know which direction the pointer is going, I'll show both. There are some gotchas which could be problematic for you involving calling conventions. `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` and `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` assume the function pointer will be StdCall so if you don't have access to the unmanaged library to make sure the function pointer is standard call (I think C defaults to cdecl unfortunately), you'd have to create an unmanaged shim library to change the calling convention, unless there is some other way I don't know about.

This would be the header of a C DLL I named "UnmanagedLib.dll".

```
typedef void ( __stdcall *WRITE_CALLBACK)(int hMountEnv, unsigned __int64 NumBytesWritten, void* pContext);

extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) WRITE_CALLBACK __stdcall FunctionProducingFunctionPointer(void);
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall FunctionConsumingFunctionPointer(WRITE_CALLBACK callback);
}
```

This would be the CPP file of the DLL.

```
#include "UnmanagedLib.h"

void __stdcall SampleFunction(int hMountEnv, unsigned __int64 NumBytesWritten, void* pContext)
{
}

WRITE_CALLBACK __stdcall FunctionProducingFunctionPointer(void)
{
    return &SampleFunction;
}

void __stdcall FunctionConsumingFunctionPointer(WRITE_CALLBACK callback)
{
    // sample call
    (*callback)(0,0,NULL);
}
```

And lastly, this is a C# program to make use of the DLL.

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void WRITE_CALLBACK(int hMountEnv, ulong NumBytesWritten, IntPtr pContext);

    [DllImport("UnmanagedLib.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FunctionProducingFunctionPointer();

    [DllImport("UnmanagedLib.dll")]
    public static extern void FunctionConsumingFunctionPointer(IntPtr functionPointer);

    public static void SampleFunction(int hMountEnv, ulong NumBytesWritten, IntPtr pContext)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var functionDelegateToManagedSampleFunction = new WRITE_CALLBACK(SampleFunction);
        var functionDelegateToUnmanagedSampleFunction = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(FunctionProducingFunctionPointer(), typeof(WRITE_CALLBACK));

        // call the unmanaged sample function via its pointer
        functionDelegateToUnmanagedSampleFunction.DynamicInvoke(new object[] {0,0ul,null});

        // pass the managed sample function to the unmanaged code
        FunctionConsumingFunctionPointer(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(functionDelegateToManagedSampleFunction));
    }
}
```

Comment: That link is for C++/CLI (Managed C++), not C#.

Comment: Thank you AnitKryst. I forgate to post my main function:         int __stdcall WriteFile
(
 int hMountEnv, 
 const char* pFullyQualifiedSourceFilePath,
 const char* pFullyQualifiedDestinationFilePath,
 const WRITE_CALLBACK pCallbackFunction,
 void* pContext
)

Comment: Declare your delegate with the attribute [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] to change the expected calling convention. Very handy!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like more of a delegate than a function/method itself. You wouldn't call this, this would be supplied as a function pointer to something else. The equivalent might be something like this:

```
public delegate void WRITE_CALLBACK(int hMountEnv, uint numBytesWritten, object pContext);
```